# samsung tab3 returns wrong screen resolution

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

Working on a Flash Video player project, it would be playable in Android & iOs

The output has come perfectly in win xp & win 7 desktops. The screen and alignment of various objects was perfect in desktop. We checked it in 4:3 & 16:9 monitors, it was perfect.

[Check desktop screen shoot](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/yourphotos?pid=5995741186049907074&oid=110391511166630042239)

Here Windows Desktop view of the app. The pink colour border streches to fill the boundry of the display area. This is perfect.

But displays wrongly in  Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 SM-T211

[Check screen shot taken in Samsung Tab3](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/yourphotos?pid=5995741375869013010&oid=110391511166630042239)

But the same app when displayed in Samsung Tab 3, the pink border does not touches the boundary of the screen.

Comment: how do you determine the width/height of your swf movie? through stage.stageWidth/Height? because that doesn't work on android. use a workaround like stage.fullscreenWidth/Height for android applications

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now.
>
I changed all my 
>
stage.stageWidth/Height >>> stage.fullscreenWidth/Height

Comment: Always use full[width/height]. It's a bit annoying to remember that, but works like a charm on all devices. Don't know the real reason why they've got so much obsolete code, I think because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hi Dodger, please post your reply as answer. So that we can close this. Thanks